# CodeIgniter - Count rows active record joint

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord

I'm trying to better understand how CI works.

This is my first table, *app_news*:

```
id / name
```

My second is *app_news_comments*:

```
id / id_news / comment
```

The model I use in order to display news informations is:

```
public function get_news($where = array()) {
    return $this->db->select('*')
        ->from('app_news')
        ->where($where)
        ->get()
        ->result();
}
```

The model I use in order to count comments for a news is:

```
public function count_comment($id_news) {

    return (int) $this->db->where(array('id_news' => $id_news)
        ->count_all_results('app_news_comments');

}
```

The first solution I have is to print a foreach on my view and putting the *count_comment* function inside the loop in order to count how much comments I have however I won't respect the MVC pattern. How can I do so ?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to get that information is using this query:

```
SELECT 
app_news.id,
app_news.name,
COUNT(app_news_comments.id)
FROM app_news_comments
JOIN app_news ON app_news_comments.id_news = app_news.id
GROUP BY app_news_comments.id_news
```

So, you need to create a query using Active Record on Codeigniter or you could add the directly, because Active Record on Codeigniter have some restrictions. 
However, you could use this way on Codeigniter to create the query:

```
$this->db->select('[YOUR FIELDS AND COUNT]', FALSE)
         ->from('app_news_comments') .... etc
```

and to add the query directly:

```
$this->db->query('[QUERY HERE]');
```

I hope this help you.